# combine keyword THIS refers component angular and THIS keyword refers to javascript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, angular6, this

I want to use code of javascript inside Component(typescript) of angular6
and when I need to put a dynamic value from html with ngModel I use the keyword this of class(component angular) and I do this inside javascript method. this is exactly my problem the javascript compiler dont found the variable in my example named 'name' of type String and give me an error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

this is my code

```
export class ClassComponent {

  public name: String = 'test';

  constructor() {

  }

  testThis() {
    function loadFile(url, callback) {
     console.log('this for function javascript',this.name); // <= prbolem here
    }
    loadFile('./assets/file.docx', function (error, content) {

    });
  }
}

// in html
<button (click)="testThis">valid</button>
```